# How can styled-components not change the class name every time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I use `styled-components` and `@bit/formidablelabs.react-animations.flash` to animate the images. ClassNmae changes with each run!

Is there a way to keep class names fixed?

actually, I need to save the runtime changes as HTML and use it again later, so changing the class name every time it ruins the work and the animation does not run.

```
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";

import Flash from "@bit/formidablelabs.react-animations.flash";

const FlashAnimation = keyframes`${Flash}`;
const FlashDiv = styled.div`animation: infinite 5s ${FlashAnimation};`;

<FlashDiv>
  <img .../>
</FlashDiv>
```

Comment: Does adding an extra container where you know the class name help reference it?
`<div className="thisStaysTheSame">
<FlashDiv >
  <img .../>
</FlashDiv>
</div>
`

Comment: @GaryB .No, I just save the photo and animation as HTML and then I want to show it somewhere else!